# When trying to create Sphinx documentation on read the docs - complains about libpulse-mainloop-glib.so.0

Tags: read-the-docs

Docs are building from this repo: https://github.com/djotaku/ELDonationTracker/tree/26858f5d174bb44658f59a7e080265bd1a8b3216

Output goes here: https://eldonationtracker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

At the time that I'm writing this question (hence why I used the tree URL in case someone finds this question in the future), the documentation for the gui and call_tracker modules fails. (It produces an empty page with just the title).

This works fine on my machine.

When I look at read-the-docs build output, I see this error: 
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'call_tracker' from module 'eldonationtracker'; the following exception was raised:
libpulse-mainloop-glib.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Same for the GUI.

The modules can be found at:

https://github.com/djotaku/ELDonationTracker/blob/26858f5d174bb44658f59a7e080265bd1a8b3216/eldonationtracker/call_tracker.py

and

https://github.com/djotaku/ELDonationTracker/blob/26858f5d174bb44658f59a7e080265bd1a8b3216/eldonationtracker/gui.py

What can I do to make this documentation work?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem. It's because PyQt5.QtMultimedia tries to open that `libpulse-mainloop-glib.so.0` pulseaudio library, which is not installed on the ReadTheDocs systems. Your `gui.py` imports `call_tracker`, so it's just propagating the error which is why it doesn't work either.

I worked around this by wrapping the QtMultimedia import in a try block:

```
try:
    from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent
except:
    pass
```

Because ReadTheDocs doesn't actually run the multimedia parts of the code (just imports the module), failing the import doesn't matter. If you actually have code that executes QMultimedia stuff on import, then you may need additional checks and workarounds.